# Jquery delay and redirect

Tags: jquery

I have this code to redirect to another site. I'm wondering if someone can help me building a 5s delay into this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(location).attr("href","www.example.com") 
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Use a `setTimeout()`. However I'm a little confused as this is just updating the attribute of an element, it doesn't actually redirect the page at all.

Comment: http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Redirect-to-another-page-after-delay-5-seconds-some-seconds-using-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  setTimeout(function(){
         $(location).attr("href","www.example.com");
   }, 5000);
```

more detail could be find at below link
[Check the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)